# Multiple ready in jQuery 2.2

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have in my page two $(document).ready In first i load a list. In second foreach the list carried in the first.

But, somestimes the second ready load first. And another time first read load.

I'm try use in first $(document).trigger('rb') in second $(windows).bind('rb', function. And It's the same problem.

I'm try replace second ready to: $(window).load(... And and it did not work.

Is there any solution for this case?

How to load second $ready for last?

Thank you. And sorry my english

Comment: you can always use only 1 ready

Comment: you can have multiple, give the sample code or fiddle so that can check

Comment: Yes i need two readys. I'm use spring mvc. and in header i'm use to load first list in ready, and in second i use to verify list from first ready

Comment: on click of first list  are you showing second list? Need some code what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes example code: http://pastebin.com/PdQ8WXDa

Comment: You don't need two. Just delete the one you want to execute last, and place the code that was inside below the code in the remaining one.

Comment: ANON, I cited an example of two, but in the project there are 5 ready to carry permits and lists at $ ready. I use SPRING and the restful

Comment: You definitely don't need two, since `$(document).ready(function () {
   console.log('foo');
   console.log('bar');
});` is exactly the same as `$(document).ready(function () {
   console.log('foo');
});
$(document).ready(function () {   
   console.log('bar');
});`

Comment: i'm validate into webservice and return the validation from use. this is most be complex in my project. when i refresh page he call first ready, sometimes call second ready. so did the validation in webservice